# R powerTransform fails on seemingly okay data

Tags: r

I'm having problems with `powerTransform` - for example it has just failed to transform a perfectly ordinary (to me) looking variable, with the following error

```
Error in optim(start, llik, hessian = TRUE, method = method, ...) :
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

Here is the data: http://www.tropic.org.uk/~crispin/boxcoxerror

```
> require(car)
> data = read.table("boxcoxerror")
> mean(data)
      V1
39401.55
> sd(data)
     V1
5381.04
> powerTransform(data$V1)
Error in optim(start, llik, hessian = TRUE, method = method, ...) :
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

Any hints?

Comment: I think we would actually need reproducible data (i.e., the full data set, or *a* full data set that has the problem). For me, `set.seed(1001); z <- rnorm(81,mean=39401,sd=5381); car::powerTransform(z)` works.  I think this should be migrated to stackoverflow, though ...

Comment: See my edit - data now included

Comment: Ben, you may be correct, but I am hopeful we can provide some insight here at stats: the issue is of statistical interest.  Bob, if you don't get some help on this (say, within a day), then just flag it for migration.  Meanwhile, I am unable to reproduce your error: the output is `Estimated transformation parameters 
  data$V1 
-2.932667`  (R 2.11.1, 64 bit Windows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's so funny about this data -- it doesn't look odd in any particular ways (the coefficient of variation is reasonable, there's nothing glaringly weird in the histogram ...) However, here are some possible routes forward.

```
require(car)
bcdata = unlist(read.table(url("http://www.tropic.org.uk/~crispin/boxcoxerror")))
mean(bcdata)
sd(bcdata)
hist(bcdata,freq=FALSE)
lines(density(bcdata))
```

Reproduce the error (R 2.14.1, 32-bit Linux)

```
powerTransform(bcdata)
```

L-BFGS-B, the optimizer used internally, is notoriously sensitive to scaling issues.  This appears to work:

```
powerTransform(bcdata/1000)
```

Oddly enough, `boxcox` gives quite different answers based on scaling too:

```
m <- MASS::boxcox(lm(bcdata~1),lambda=seq(-4,2,by=0.05))
m2 <- MASS::boxcox(lm(bcdata/1000~1),lambda=seq(-8,2,by=0.05))
m2$x[which.max(m2$y)]  ## agrees pretty well with powerTransform()
```

The other thing that worries me is that the power transformation being suggested is so extreme -- do we really need a power of nearly -5 to normalize these data?

Perhaps someone who's thinking more carefully about the actual analytical details of the Box-Cox/power transformations can explain what's happening here.

Comment: The result (I get -3, not -5, but it's still too extreme) is an artifact: these data are offset from zero too much to benefit from a pure Box-Cox transformation.  There's no substitute for good exploration and visualization of data.  That's why many people eschew automated and likelihood-based methods to (blindly) obtain such transformations, despite their ease of use.

Comment: The point that I didn't appreciate previously is that the Box-Cox likelihood profile is not invariant to scale changes ...

Comment: Hmm...it *ought* to be invariant.  If it isn't, we should question the technique being used for the estimation.  Note, however, that it will be sensitive to affine changes of *location*.

Comment: Doesn't dividing by 1000 and getting a different answer imply that it's not scale-invariant?  Or do we write this off as effectively changing both scale and location? (S -> S/1000, L -> L/1000)

Comment: The best solution *is* scale invariant.  Therefore, if the solution obtained by an algorithm is *not* scale invariant, there's a problem with it.

Comment: So maybe I should scale my data to have mean=0 and sd=1 first then?  Although I appreciate the point about good exploration/visualization,  I have a large number of variables to test - 10,000 or so - and am running bivariate regression (of each variable with the target) to identify candidates for a more conscientious analysis...

Comment: ...though thinking about that, if I scale as suggested, how can I box-cox transform data that contains negative values?